# find latitude and longitude using distance

Tags: javascript, dictionary, geolocation, geospatial

I want to find Latitude, for example

```
Point A = (18.5204303,73.8567437)
Point B = (x,73.8567437)
Distance =20KM(Kilometers)
```

I need to find the latitude(x) of Point B, that is 20 KM from point A.Longitude should be same. Help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't you need an angle as well? Otherwise there is an infinite number of `B = (x, y)` points matching your criteria - on a circle with 20km radius and centre in `A`...

Comment: Yes,i need Angular radius, But i don't know how to find it.

Comment: so you have a single equation with two unknowns - math is against you ;-). You need to know both: radius and angle to be able to find exactly one `B`.

Comment: I checked this link 
http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates

(section 3.1)
sort out with some formula,But it is not matching with the circle drawn at 20km

Comment: i apologize, here longitude will be fixed that is in 
Point A = (18.5204303,73.8567437)
Point B = (x,73.8567437)
Distance =20KM(Kilometers)

Comment: You **must** add this to your question, this is an important detail.

Comment: apologize Tomasz Nurkiewicz,hope u understand my question help me

Comment: @Nishu, its a perfect question for http://gis.stackexchange.com/. You can try there too..

Comment: So you just want a point 20km north or south of point A? Assuming a spherical earth that's easy given the radius. Slightly harder for elliptical earth. High school maths. Slight complications also at distances less than 20km from the poles. But workable...

Comment: Thank you all, i figured out solution from this link. http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html#Destination%20point%20given%20distance%20and%20bearing%20from%20start%20point and i posted my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found answer for my question

```
var lat1 = 18.5204303;
    var lon1 = 73.8567437;
    var d = 20;   //Distance travelled
    var R = 6371;
    var brng = 0;
    var LatMax;
    brng = toRad(brng); 
    var lat1 = toRad(lat1), lon1 = toRad(lon1);
    var lat2 = Math.asin( Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(d/R) + 
                      Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(brng) );

    var lon2 = lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(lat1), 
                             Math.cos(d/R)-Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2));
        lon2 = (lon2+3*Math.PI) % (2*Math.PI) - Math.PI;  
    lat2= toDeg(lat2);
    lon2= toDeg(lon2);
    alert(lat2);
    alert(lon2);

function toRad(Value) {
    /** Converts numeric degrees to radians */
    return Value * Math.PI / 180;
}
 function toDeg(Value) {
   return Value * 180 / Math.PI;
}
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this should be an answer or a comment. But since I can't write comments yet I'll write an answer.

[This](http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#Rhumb) page is a great source for doing distance calculations. In this case you are probably looking for code to calculate the new position when traveling along a rhumb line from a given position. Quote from linked page:

> To find the lat/lon of a point on true course tc, distance d from (lat1,lon1) along a rhumbline (initial point cannot be a pole!):

```
lat= lat1+d*cos(tc)
IF (abs(lat) > pi/2) "d too large. You can't go this far along this rhumb line!"
IF (abs(lat-lat1) < sqrt(TOL))
{
    q=cos(lat1)
}
ELSE 
{
    dphi=log(tan(lat/2+pi/4)/tan(lat1/2+pi/4))
    q= (lat-lat1)/dphi
}
dlon=-d*sin(tc)/q
lon=mod(lon1+dlon+pi,2*pi)-pi
```

The link is still useful but you will have to use some algebra to solve for a known longitude and unknown course. Since you are quite far north great circle distances may be more useful than rhumb lines. But I guess that depends on the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert in this. But i used to calculate the distance between two points using the formulae by [movable-type](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

Please check the site. it ll give you some hint. I think this [destination](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html#destPoint)  and [rhumblines](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html#rhumblines) formulae  are similar to your requirement. Have a look

Comment: These are not an algorithms, just formulae.

Comment: you can mark it as a answer if it helped.. so someone can find it useful

Comment: Thank you Ramesh, i figured out logic for my question through your link and posted my answer.

Comment: @Nishu, that's great. You dont have to accept my answer. just upvote it and mark your own answer as a accepted one. since thats the complete one...